# Nonfailable enum initializer with default value

Tags: swift, enums

Is there a way to define an enum, when initialized from `rawValue` will default to some value instead of failing? Useful in cases where the value may be unexpected (i.e. server API errors)

Comment: Can't you just override that `init` that takes the `rawValue` argument...?  And `return super.init(rawValue: rawValue) ?? yourDefaultValue`?

Comment: ...but if the value may be unexpected, an `enum` might be the wrong avenue... or failure might be what you want...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mean something like that?

```
enum ErrorCode: Int {
    case NoErr = 0, Err1, Err2, LastErr, DefaultErr

    init(value: Int) {
        if (value > LastErr.rawValue) {
            self = .DefaultErr
        } else {
            self = ErrorCode(rawValue: value)!
        }
    }
}

let error: ErrorCode = .LastErr
let anotherError: ErrorCode = ErrorCode(value: 99)
```

Here is another variation:

```
enum ErrorCode: Int {
    case NoErr = 0, Err1, Err2, LastErr

    init?(value: Int) {
        if (value > 3) {
            return nil
        } else {
            self = ErrorCode(rawValue: value)!
        }

    }
}

let error: ErrorCode = .LastErr
let anotherError: ErrorCode? = ErrorCode(value: 99)
```

which is equivalent to :

```
enum ErrorCode: Int {
    case NoErr = 0, Err1, Err2, LastErr
}

let anotherError: ErrorCode? = ErrorCode(rawValue: 99)
```

because as Apple doc is stating:

> NOTE
>
> The raw value initializer is a failable initializer, because not every
>   raw value will return an enumeration member. For more information, see
>   Failable Initializers.

But in general, if you want to use enum with rawvalue, you should expect an optional and treat the nil returned value as a default error case outside the enum definition. That would be my recommendation.

Comment: Yes, it is probably better to expect nil value, but I opted for your solution for sake of convenience