# Overriding Enum init?(rawValue: String) to not be optional

Tags: ios, swift, enums, initialization

I want to have init from rawValue for my enum in Swift to return default value if rawValue init will return nil.
Right now I have something like this:

```
public init(fromRawValue: String){
        self = Language(rawValue: fromRawValue) ?? .English
}
```

I don't like this because it is completely new initializer.
I tried to make something like this:

```
public init(rawValue: String){
        self = Language(rawValue: fromRawValue) ?? .English
}
```

But I have got runtime exception with bad access. Can I somehow make it work or I just have to use this new and I cannot override original one to not be optional?

I would like to know if it possible to override original init from rawValue not workaround with completely new one that is using failable one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nonfailable enum initializer with default value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30633981/nonfailable-enum-initializer-with-default-value)

Answer (score 158, accepted):

The default initializer is `failable`. It means that if the received parameter does not match a valid enum case it does return `nil`.

Now you want to do 2 incompatibles things:

1. You want to **redefine** the default initializer making it not failable. In fact you want a default enum value created when the received param is not valid.
2. Inside your redefined initializer you want to call a failable initializer (which no longer exists) using the same name of the new one.

This is not possible, I the 3 possible solutions as follows:

1. Creating a different init

You define a new not failable initializer with a default value, a different parameter name and inside it you call the default failable initializer.

```
enum Language: String {
    
    case english = "English", italian = "Italian", french = "French"
    
    init(fromRawValue: String) {
        self = Language(rawValue: fromRawValue) ?? .english
    }
}
```

2. Redefining the default init

You redefine the default initializer, you make it not failable and you write the full logic inside it.

```
enum Language: String {
    
    case english = "English", italian = "Italian", french = "French"
    
    init(rawValue: String) {
        switch rawValue {
        case "Italian": self = .italian
        case "French": self = .french
        default: self = .english
        }
    }
}
```

3. Creating a static func

```swift
enum Language: String {

    case english = "English", italian = "Italian", french = "French"

    static func build(rawValue: String) -> Language {
        return Language(rawValue: rawValue) ?? .english
    }
}
```

Now you can build a `Language` value writing:

```
let italian = Language.build(rawValue: "Italian") // Italian
let defaultValue = Language.build(rawValue: "Wrong input") // English
```

Comment: Fantastic answer. The "self = ..." was invaluable. All sorts of hidden Swift nuggets in this lang  :)

Comment: You can replace `Language` in approach #1 's initializer to `type(of: self).init` for a more generic approach.

Answer (score 11):

Adding to Luca's solution for redefining the default init, it is possible to additionally make the `rawValue` parameter type optional, which cuts down on some code at the call site when the data source is not reliable.

```
enum PrecipitationType: String {
    case rain, snow, sleet, none

    typealias RawValue = String

    init(rawValue: String?) {
        guard let rawValue = rawValue else { self = .none; return }

        switch rawValue {
            case PrecipitationType.rain.rawValue: self = .rain
            case PrecipitationType.snow.rawValue: self = .snow
            case PrecipitationType.sleet.rawValue: self = .sleet
            default: self = .none
        }
    }
}
```

When I initially tried this it generated multiple errors. The key was to redefine the `RawValue` typealias to maintain conformance to `RawRepresentable`.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to do a switch and make it more easy to edit I suggest using `CaseIterable` protocol. Here is an example:

```
enum Season: String, CaseIterable {
    case spring, summer, fall, winter, unknown

    init?(rawValue: String) {
        self = Self.allCases.first { $0.rawValue == rawValue } ?? .unknown
    }
}

print(Season(rawValue: "autumn"), Season(rawValue: "fall"))
// Prints: `unknown fall`
```